# How to concat string the Column value in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've following code in which, i want to concat a url path to image name.

```
let product_list = await Product.findAll({
      limit: limit,
      offset: offset,
      where: {
        isActive: 1
      },
      order: [
        ['createdAt', 'DESC'],
      ],
      include: { 
        model: ProductImage, 
        limit: 1, 
        offset: 0,
        attributes: [
          [db.sequelize.literal("https://abc.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ || '' || image"), 'image']
        ],
      },
    });
```

How can i get the desired output?

Comment: make sure to add the desired output to the question itself.

Comment: Where is image? in the db or in the js?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your delimiters are mismatched.  Try using double-quotes for javascript and single quotes for the SQL.

```
attributes: [
  ["concat('https://abc.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/',  image)" , 'image']
],
```

This assumes "image" is a column the ProductImage table.  I am using `concat` because our mySql instance isn't configured for `||`.